# SQL | Best practices to build SQL update query with not null values only

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Looking for best practices to build an update query with not null values.

Below the my implementation where passed parameter firstName, middleName, lastName, address can be null. I want to build an update query with not null values only. I have used multiple if condition for not null and comma separator.

```
public void updatePerson(String id, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String address) {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("UPDATE PERSON SET ");
    MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("id", id);
    boolean columnSepartor = false;

    if (firstName != null) {
        query.append(" FIRST_NAME =:firstName");
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("firstName", firstName);
        columnSepartor = true;
    }

    if (middleName != null) {
        query = columnSepartor ? query.append(", MIDDLE_NAME =:middleName") : query.append(" MIDDLE_NAME =:middleName");
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("middleName", middleName);
        columnSepartor = true;
    }

    if (lastName != null) {
        query = columnSepartor ? query.append(", LAST_NAME =:lastName") : query.append(" LAST_NAME =:lastName");
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("lastName", lastName);
        columnSepartor = true;
    }

    if (address != null) {
        query = columnSepartor ? query.append(", ADDRESS =:address") : query.append(" ADDRESS =:address");
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("address", address);
    }

    query.append(" WHERE ID  =:id");
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query.toString(), mapSqlParameterSource);
}
```

Please suggest best practices to target such use case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to update only those columns in a table that are currently **not** null for a given id? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes..

Comment: To "build an update query" in oracle, especially if we don't know the column names, would require dynamic sql. But if you just want to run an update statement, the  method in  the answers here will definitely be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my first choice of implementation for that requirement. It's small, it's easily understood and it will perform just as well for the vast majority of applications.

The **coalesce** expression returns the first non-null value. In this case it returns the new value (if there is one), else it returns the existing value from the column.

```
update person
   set first_name  = coalesce(:firstName,  first_name)
      ,middle_name = coalesce(:middleName, middle_name)
      ,last_name   = coalesce(:lastName,   last_name)
      ,address     = coalesce(:address,    address)
 where id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build an SQL command as follows:

```
UPDATE <your table>
  SET FirstName = NVL(PassedFirstName , FirstName) ,
      MidName   = NVL(PassedMidName   , MidName  ) , 
      LastName  = NVL(PassedLastName  , LastName ) ...
 WHERE...
```

which means, for any passed null value, update the record with the original value.